# How can i make an audio play event stop after 1 minute?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

This is my play audio code but i need to make it stop after 1 minute.

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
     }
 </script>`
```

Do i need to create a new event?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just add a `setTimeout` call after the code, to run the passed function after 60seconds.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById("my_audio").play();

     setTimeout(function(){
       document.getElementById("my_audio").stop();
     }, 60000);

   }
 </script>`
```

You can improve this code by saving your audio control into a variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload=function(){
     let myAudio = document.getElementById("my_audio")
     myAudio.play();

     setTimeout(function(){
       myAudio.stop();
     }, 60000);

   }
 </script>`
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying back so quickly. I have added this script to the website but it does not seem to stop the song from playing. You can see the code here https://www.maephila.com/

Comment: @JeseReyes Your code is ok but you have another js error in your page and I guess that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeseReyes There's a SSL permissions so it cannot play the content until everything is HTTP. At least that's the issue on Firefox